# How to get the certain value from column description Postgres

Tags: psql

I have a column stating "Description", that holds log details of a process.
Log contains many entries, I would like to only get only line that states "Error Value" and followed by 5-6 words from the entry(that describes error)

Do I have to use SUBSTRING? OR Is this possible? Pleas suggest

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table where description like '%Error Value%'
```

This will be expensive query. If you would know the very start of value, you could remove starting `%` which would make it much faster if you have index on that column...